# add string to string array then add to combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hello i have string which is something like this

> Dim products As String = "SANDWICH-1%MANGO JUICE-10%"

now i appended the % sign between every product while saving the combobox items in Microsoft access database

now what i want to do is to make this product string which i fetched from the database to add every single product in combobox4

i tried

```
products = products.Replace("%", "','")

Dim array() As String = {products}

For Each column As String In array
    ComboBox4.Items.Add(column)
Next
```

but the replace dont work properly the data comes in combobox in same line
i want it as
index 0 = SANDWICH-1
index 1 = MANGO JUICE-10

this way if you can help or this is how i appended the data to one string while inserting it into Microsoft access database

```
Dim productsincarts As String = String.Empty
        For Each itm As String In ComboBox4.Items
            productsincarts &= itm & "%"
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
For Each item In products.Split(CChar("%"))
    ComboBox4.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Probably better ways but this will achieve what you want.

Comment: hello thanks bro it works but it adds one entry as null string and from second i can see the entry text any fix

Comment: i fixed it myself removed the item at index 0 from combobox thanks i am okay now

Comment: @android_guy Glad it worked, if you mark this as an answer it shows others what worked for you without them having to read the comments.